# Make UIPopoverController NOT resign on outside touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm showing a UIPopovercontroller, which naturally dismisses itself when the user touches anywhere outside of it.

Is there a way to make it NOT dismiss itself when touched at all? I'd rather manually dismiss it when the user does an action within.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the docs on UIPopoverController:

> passthroughViews
>   An array of views that the user can interact with while the popover is visible.
>
> @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *passthroughViews

Just set that to whatever you want to remain interactive (self.view for everything), and the popover will 'ignore' a dismissal from these views.  It's quite handy, and available in 3.2+, making it über-easy to write legacy code.

Comment: Fantastic solution Mr.CodaFi.